# LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/fabio/projects/task-manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rubygems, environment, abort

So guys, when I try run rails routes, appear this error.

rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/fabio/projects/task-manager-api/config/api_version_constraint
/home/fabio/projects/task-manager-api/config/routes.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/fabio/projects/task-manager-api/config/routes.rb:1:in`'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in`block in load'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in`load'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in load_paths'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in`each'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `load_paths'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:20:in`reload!'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:30:in `block in updater'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in`execute'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:130:in`block in '
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in`run'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in`run_initializers'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/home/fabio/projects/task-manager-api/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in`require_environment!'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in`block in perform'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in`invoke'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/fabio/projects/task-manager-api/bin/rails:9:in`require'
/home/fabio/projects/task-manager-api/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`load'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in`call'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in`'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`'
/home/fabio/projects/task-manager-api/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/fabio/projects/task-manager-api/bin/spring:15:in`'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in`'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Someboody have any idea?

Comment: Posting your routes.rb would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so people can solve it by posting the following line in the application.rb
config.autoload_paths + = Dir ["# {config.root} / lib / ** /"]